# Apps Script: Increment dates in format day/month/year for multiple columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**ISSUE:** 
I have 4 columns: A, B, C and D. Column A is filled on a daily basis with dates in format **day/month/year**. Now I want to make sure that anytime dates are written in column A, these dates are copied to columns B, C and D and incremented there by 1 day.

***Example:***
 Let´s say the user has just written the dates 18/10/2021, 19/10/2021 and 20/10/2021 in 3 different rows in column A in format day/month/year. These dates should be copied and incremented by 1 day in each of the next columns, so that I can have following results:

Column B: 19/10/2021, 20/10/2021 and 21/10/2021
Column C: 20/10/2021, 21/10/2021 and 22/10/2021
Column D: 21/10/2021, 22/10/2021 and 23/10/2021

**QUESTION:**
The script below can copy just 1 date from column A and increment it by 1 day in column B. But how can I ensure that it does the same thing in columns B, C and D for more than just 1 row?

```
// Get date from column A, increment it by 1 day and write this incremented date in colum B
function incrementDateInGermanFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date = new Date(ss.getRange(1, 1).getValue());
  var newDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1));
  var newFormattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(newDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
  ss.getRange(1, 2).setValue(newFormattedDate)
}
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula. Put this in cell `B1`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    isnumber(A1:A), 
    { A1:A + 1, A1:A + 2, A1:A + 3 }, 
    iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

Format the result columns `B:D` as **Format > Number > Date**.

If you need to do this in Apps Script for some reason not mentioned in your question, use something like this:

```
function incrementDates() {
  const datesRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:A');
  const dates = datesRange.getValues().flat();
  const result = dates.map(date => {
    if (!date || !date.getDate) {
      return [null, null, null];
    }
    const dayNumber = date.getDate();
    return [
      new Date(date.setDate(dayNumber + 1)),
      new Date(date.setDate(dayNumber + 2)),
      new Date(date.setDate(dayNumber + 3)),
    ];
  });
  datesRange.offset(0, 1, result.length, result[0].length)
    .setValues(result);
}
```

The date format used in the spreadsheet does not come into play in this. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

Comment: First off, thank you so much for helping me. Just run your app script (so, the second one) after formatting the results columns and got this error message: "ReferenceError: date is not defined". Any idea how and why I got this error message? Thanks :)

Comment: Edited the function in the answer to check that the values in `A1:A` are actually dates.

Comment: It now works like magic. Thank you so much, and have a great weekend :)